# PHP include scope class

Tags: php, class, include, scope

so I have this problem I have 3 files like

2.php

```
<?php
$variable = 4;
?>
```

1.php

```
<?php
class foo {
function bar() {include_once('2.php');}
}
?>
```

index.php

```
<?php
include_once('1.php');
$foo = new foo;
foo->bar();
echo $variable;
?>
```

Why it tells me variable has no value ?
If I do like this

```
<?php
include_once('1.php');
$foo = new foo;
foo->bar();
include_once('2.php');
echo $variable;
?>
```

It won't work either.
Only in this way

```
<?php
include_once('1.php');
$foo = new foo;
//foo->bar();
include_once('2.php');
echo $variable;
?>
```

It will work, any explanation?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing [`include`](http://php.net/include) and [`include_once`](http://php.net/include_once).

When you use the latter the file loading and thus variable declaration will only occur *once*. And if you do so within the method scope, it won't get declared a second time in the global scope. Or vice versa.

Comment: It behaves as it should. You should explain why you expected a different outcome.

Comment: So, I expect the include to work as it does in the global space. If I include something everything included should be visible after it has been included.
The class I'm making is a wrapper made to throw a special error when the Include fails. It all works, except, the include itself.

Comment: The include does not work in the global scope. It always runs the script in the local scope. The local scope might incidentally be the global scope, but it ain't always. If you run it into a method, then the var will only be declared there.

Comment: So, how can I put it in a method but making it include like being in the global scope ?

Comment: You can't. The include script itself has to globalize the variables, if that is what's supposed to happen.

Answer (score 0):

The scope of `$variable` is only within the `bar()` function

See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: If I remember correctly, in php 4 I did a similar thing and it worked, how can I make it the same way but making it visible on index.php ?

Comment: Well in your first index example you don't include `1.php`, which would make `foo` undefined, so that might be a problem there.